# I need call a Java class to C# with Unity

Tags: java, c#, android, object, unity-game-engine

I need to transfer data from a Java class to C# with Unity but response.Call (SetValue, "args") does not work.

The code does not work when testing on an android system.

Java Class:

```
public class Communication
{

  private int id;
  private String type;
  private String[] value;

  public Communication() {}

  public int GetID()
  {
    return id;
  }

  public void SetID(int value)
  {
    id = value;
  }

  public String GetType()
  {
    return type;
  }

  public void SetType(String value)
  {
    type = value;
  }

  public String[] GetValue()
  {
    return value;
  }

  public void SetValue(String[] value)
  {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

C# code from unity (I need to call the function `SetValue()`):

```
public void Response()
{
    AndroidJavaObject manager = new AndroidJavaObject("cicese.mooding.brain.BrainManager");
    AndroidJavaObject response = new AndroidJavaObject("cicese.mooding.brain.data.interaction.Communication");
    string stringParameter = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name;
    object[] args = new object[] { stringParameter };

    response.Call("SetValue",args);
    args = new object[] { response };
    AndroidJavaObject data = manager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("receiveDataFromGUI", args);
    inter = Interaction.AndroidJavaToCSharp(data); 
    }
```

Comment: It does not work.....What happens? Do you get an exception? Any error?

Comment: When the android app (APK) is generated with unity and executed on a smart phone it does not call the SetValue method

Comment: That does not answer the question...Wrap `response.Call("SetValue",args);` in a try catch block then tell us the log. Right now, you are not telling us your problem other than *it doesn't work*.